# How to generate list of years

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I am trying to generate lists of years from N year to the current year of the user.
How can I automatically generate a list of years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the current year the user is in by using `DateTime.now().year`. After that you can have a loop that starts from the `N` year and stops when it reaches the current year.

The following is one way to do it:

```
List<int> getYears(int year) {
  int currentYear = DateTime.now().year;

  List<int> yearsTilPresent = [];

  while (year <= currentYear) {
    yearsTilPresent.add(year);
    year++;
  }
  
  return yearsTilPresent;
}
```

You can read more about `DateTime` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html).

Comment: This solution worked. But is there any way I can convert the years returned as string?

Comment: Yes, you can list the return method as a `List<String>`, and use `yearsTilPresent.add(year.toString())` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Try with this

```
      int currentYear = DateTime.now().year;
      int startingYear = 2000;
      List yearList = List.generate((currentYear-startingYear)+1, (index) => startingYear+index);
```